# Issues with uninstalling create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am running `npm uninstall create-react-app`, and it returns

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/Documents/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/Documents/package.json'
npm WARN Documents No description
npm WARN Documents No repository field.
npm WARN Documents No README data
npm WARN Documents No license field.
```

I want to update my create-react-app version, and apparently they no longer support global installs. When I installed CRA the first time (a while ago), it was installed globally. Now, I am trying to update it, and I'm running into issues. I ran `npm update create-react-app`, however my terminal just blinks for a second and returns to the prompt. I, therefore, decided to uninstall `create-react-app` altogether and reinstall it, however now I'm running into the above warnings/issues.

Any thoughts on what may be going on?

Edit:

When I run `npm i create-react-app`, it also throws the above `WARN`s, but it also says

```
+ create-react-app@3.3.0 // <---
added 1 package and audited 578 packages in 1.787s
```

However, when I run the command `create-react-app --version` again, it says `3.2.0`

Edit 2:

I've ran `npm i -g create-react-app` several times, but that throws:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:Documents me$ npm i -g create-react-app
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2019-12-23T08_07_29_158Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You need to use global flag (-g)
so it would be: npm uninstall -g create-react-app . And you would use same flag for installing or updating

Comment: After running that command, I get the response `up to date in 0.031s`. However, if I run `create-react-app --version` right after, it says `3.2.0`

Comment: What OS's you running ?

Comment: I'm using MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 109):

After globally uninstalling `create-react-app`, I was still getting an error that my `create-react-app` was out of date. Here's what solved that for me:

After

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Run

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Then try reinstalling `create-react-app` in the proper working directory:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: I kept getting the message saying I should not have CRA installed globally even though I had run the global uninstall. I just needed to do the `clear-npx-cache`. Upvoted for that.

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: fs_1.rmSync is not a function` when trying to use clear-npx-cache

Comment: `npx clear-npx-cache` worked.

Answer (score 27):

To uninstall it completely try running

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

some times this command may not remove the package completely. if so just check the directory 
where its located by

```
which create-react-app
```

and it will give you some directory like /usr/local/bin/create-react-app. 
just remove it manually by

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
```

now you can install create-react-app by

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

but however, it is not recommended to install it globally from v3.3.0.so just use

```
npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just install over it by rerunning this command.
`sudo npm i -g create-react-app`

I personally use NCU (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to update all my node stuff. It works globally and per project.

Answer (score 4):

For windows 10 users
go to `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm`
then delete the create-react-app files

Comment: nothing suggested here worked for me on windows 10 using ReactJS in Visual Studio until I did this.  I also deleted "npm-cache" if I run into problems I will post them here.

Answer (score 4):

#### **Going further with Windows 10**

While [Dhruv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813937/3025856) solved this problem for me (finding and deleting **`create-react-app`** and then reinstalling), I still had a few problems finding `create-react-app` in my Windows 10 system.

I was trying to find my global install, (`where create-react-app` produced no results for me) and, as far as I could tell, it was never installed. But using an elevated cmd prompt by using the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> keys, selecting "Windows PowerShell (Admin)" and then navigating to my desired working directory, I could then execute **`npx create-react-app my-test-app`** and it created a working react directory.

It seems in Windows 10, elevated cmd prompt is the way forward for using **`npx create-react-app my-test-app`** successfully. I am not sure why this is though. As previously it was working (at least for me) with the normal cmd prompt.

Answer (score 3):

**For windows**

tried `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
that didn't work for me.

I did the following and it worked:

1. Elevated cmd prompt: `where create-react-app`
   it was somewhere in the system files under yarn. follow that path  and delete both the files.
2. Go to the working directory, in my case a folder inside documents. 
   run `npx create-react-app my-test-app`

This will create a new folder called `my-test-app` and you can follow the rest of the instructions on the react app website.

cd into that new folder, run `yarn start`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. Tried many solutions but no success.

At last, I was came to a video on youtube that helped me to overcome this issue.

Link to this video is
[create-react-app error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZRGvyI80s8)

The command I used is

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app ; npm i -g npm@latest ; npm cache clean -f
```

NOTE: Depending on your node version, you might need to use **&&** at the place of **;**

Answer (score 0):

if you are a windows user like me, you can install the Bash terminal. You will be able to execute almost all the commands used in ubuntu, except the "Sudo" command. And given commands of uninstalling and others will also work! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the lack of the word ***template***.

Only the below issue command worked for me:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

[More here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/)

Answer (score 0):

For people who get the message to remove any global installs even after running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, and clear cache doesn't work, I found installing globally, then uninstalling globally helped me. So:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

I run the `npx clear-npx-cache` just in case, and it worked. I guess the new installation overwrote the leftover files that couldn't be cleaned. Also, I should mention, I used Windows 10 and also PowerShell with Admin privileges; I'm not sure if Admin is needed.

Comment: Anytime uninstalling, I got no error but a message saying up to date, audited 1 package in 217ms

found 0 vulnerabilities. I tried your method and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows solution:

1- uninstall globally `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

2- use `where create-react-app`on terminal and remove all path founded!

3- create new react app `npx create-react-app client --template typescript`

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. I had to do a search of my entire computer for "create-react-app" and delete every file and folder.
Surprisingly many of the files were in cache or in .bin folders
Once those were deleted, I was finally able to run npx create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is running `npm install create-react-app@latest` and it updated it without deleting and reinstalling (which didn't work for me too).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `npm install -g create-react-app` to install the latest version of create-react-app and then you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows 10

if `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` doesn't work, then you can delete it `manually` from these two locations (see `PATH` environment variable to find these locations):

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
```

I resolved my issue by deleting from `Yarn\bin`