# the src and public folder are not creating while using create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have previously used and installed create react app globally,but when i tried to create a new app its not working.

So i followed this :https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8097
didn't worked.

Then I tried this:[Issues with uninstalling create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451813/issues-with-uninstalling-create-react-app)
I got the same error as in that question.

I have also tried : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

and https://icetutor.com/question/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app/
I really don't know what is the issue.
When I am using the command

```
     where create-react-app
```

i got this:

```
    C:\Users\PC 2\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
    C:\Users\PC 2\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app.cmd
```

and when i use this :

```
    npm rm -rf C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
```

gives this

```
    npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\package.json'
    npm WARN saveError EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\package-lock.json.1678493388'
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\package.json'
    npm WARN Users No description
    npm WARN Users No repository field.
    npm WARN Users No README data
    npm WARN Users No license field.

    up to date in 0.058s
```

when I am using yarn to install I get

```
   C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\React>yarn create react-app test
   yarn create v1.16.0
   [1/4] Resolving packages...
   [2/4] Fetching packages...
   [3/4] Linking dependencies...
   [4/4] Building fresh packages...
   success Installed "create-react-app@3.3.0" with binaries:
   - create-react-app
```

[##########################################################################################################################################################################################] 225/225'

```
    C:\Users\Weboffice' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error Command failed.
    Exit code: 1
    Command: C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
    Arguments: test
    Directory: C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\React
    Output:

    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about 
    this command.
```

when i used yarn to uninstall I get

```
    C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\React>yarn uninstall create-react-app
    yarn run v1.16.0
    error Couldn't find a package.json file in "C:\\Users\\Weboffice PC 
    2\\React"
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about 
    this command
```

question updated.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling your global version of CRA and using “yarn create react-app myapp” (suggested yarn because it seems like you’re using it). More detail here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ Also please share more detail of what happens when you run the commands and what the result is (show folder structure of the resulting app etc).

Comment: I have edited the question with outputs using yarn, no folders where created when using it.

Comment: To uninstall the global package (you showed trying to uninstall local), run “yarn global remove create-react-app”

Comment: I’m also curious about your user name “Weboffice PC 2” given that it has spaces in it (typically discouraged). I’m a Mac user but some googling led me here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path - the error seems related to your username. Did you change it recently? Error: “...Weboffice is not recognized...”

Comment: @JBallin no I didn't changed the name.But your suggestion worked. [1/2] Removing module create-react-app...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 3.40s.

C:\Users\Weboffice PC 2\React>where create-react-app
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: but when i tried to install it shows the error as in the edit.

Comment: Glad we got a little closer. I’m still suspicious about the username having spaces in it, otherwise I don’t know why it’s not working. You could try using npm instead of yarn? npm uninstall -g create-react-app; npx create-react-app myapp

Comment: I found a work around to alter the white space in the folder and running cmd as administrator i got it worked and and could create a react app using npx. this is the link I used : https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100#issuecomment-484193572  Thank you @ JBalin for answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing that there’s an issue with the space in your username (this is a known issue with npx, for which a fix is slowly being [worked on](https://github.com/zkat/npx/pull/181)).

In the meantime, here’s a [workaround](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100#issuecomment-413815760):

> I was able to fix this in Windows by creating a directory junction to my users folder that didn't have a space in it. You can run a command like this in an administrative powershell:
>
> `cmd /c mklink /J C:\Users\myname" "C:\Users\My Name"`
>
> You can then use this junction as if it were your real user directory:
>
> `npm config set cache C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
>
> `npm config set prefix C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm`
>
> (the above should update your user .npmrc file)